No display device besides ACES on color management
I've been having trouble with colors on my scenes while trying to Texture Paint and as I searched for answers, people often talked about changing the Display Device and View Transform of the Color Management Tab. They said to switch to sRGB or others but I don't have any other option than ACES.
Is there a way to add other display device?
Thank you


What rendering engine are you using?

Do you have OCIO installed (possibly by another app)?  If Blender sees the OCIO environment variable pointing to an ACES profile, it will use that instead of the built-in sRGB/Agx color config.  You can check by going into a command line and do echo %OCIO%.

@Jakemoyo I'm using Eevee!

@MikePan Oh I did have OCIO installed from another app! I deleted the file and the colors work now, I have access to the sRGB display device! Thank you so much!
